# Page sorting isn't working with zero size

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a following code:

```
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, count, page.getSort());
```

With count = 0 it isn't working, because as I see the sorting won't work with null. Is there a way to solve this with a zero size or I should apply to count other number?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with that? And how do you expect page with size 0 to work, what exactly is the point in requesting empty page?

Comment: @Chaosfire I am downloading document and its not with zero. So I want to download it with a zero count as well

Answer (score 0):

With `count=0` your `PageRequest` translate to requesting a sorted collection without any elements.
Sorting and in fact the complete request doesn't make any sense, therefore you should not pass 0 and that is actually verified by the code:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/8e5010c490459785316e8dc55817a9ff61227290/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/domain/AbstractPageRequest.java#L27

```java
    public AbstractPageRequest(int page, int size) {

        if (page < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Page index must not be less than zero!");
        }

        if (size < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Page size must not be less than one!");
        }

        this.page = page;
        this.size = size;
    }
```